# Running bash script outside of directory

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to run a script that's in a directory I have admin rights for, but I am trying to run it from somewhere that is not the directory.. I.E. its a generate load in script that reads all the files in the directory and it gives an output based on those files. But when I try to call it from the terminal it doesn't run unless active directory is the directory where the script is located, is this a permissions issue?

I have tried running it this way:

```
sh /path/to/file/FILE
./path/to/file/FILE
```

but when I `cd` to directory and run

```
./FILE
```

it runs fine.

Permissions for my account:

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 edennis edennis       4096 Nov 14 14:35 .
```

Permissions for script:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 edennis edennis       3644 Nov 14 11:45 zScript
```

Permissions for files script is accessing:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 edennis edennis   10437424 Oct 15 10:27 document.txt
```

Contents of script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.txt

do

echo "this is my favorite file " "$file" >> output.txt;

done
```

Comment: Do you realize that `sh /path/to/file/FILE` and `./path/to/file/FILE` aren't equivalent? First one will resolve path relatively to filesystem root (`/`), while second one will work relatively to current directory. Also, you can skip `./` if you're not running the script in a current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you still remain in the current directory when you run the script. So, the line

```
for file in *.txt
```

will expand the glob (`*.txt`) to all text files in your current directory. Of course, if your current directory (**not** the script's directory!) doesn't have any text files, you won't get any output.

If you want to change to the script's directory from within the script (which would make the `*.txt` glob work), see this Stack Overflow post: [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

---

While we're at it – don't forget to [quote `"$file"` properly](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) when you use to prevent a filename with spaces from breaking your commands. It doesn't matter in your case because `echo` doesn't care about the arguments, but it's a good habit to develop.